# Problema: Warning: Undefined array key "id_articulo" in C:\xamppd\htdocs\org\actualizar.php on line 5"

Tags: php

El error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "id_articulo" in
> C:\xamppd\htdocs\org\actualizar.php on line 5

es en esta parte del código:

```
$id=$_GET['id_articulo'];
```

según me marca localhost, ¿saben que podria ser?

```
<?php 
    include("conexion.php");
    $con=conectar();
    $sql="SELECT *  FROM comercio";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

Comment: Seguro no estás enviando el parámetro... o también pruébalo con `$_GET['id_articulo'] ?? null`

Comment: <?php 
    include("conexion.php");
    $con=conectar();

$id=$_GET['id_articulo'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id_articulo='$id'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql); ""solo me marca como que no esta definido.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el código _como texto, con formato_. Como verás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios. Lee [ask] y ha el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Acabo de arreglar tu código en la pregunta, no lo estabas poniendo bien (el editor dispone de una ayuda que debes aprender para hacerlo mejor).  Aún así, viéndolo y comparándolo con tu comentario, no es lo mismo, y el código de la pregunta no tiene sentido.  Corrígelo, y cuando lo hagas fíjate que lo he encerrado entre tres comilas **invertidas** (acentos graves) que es la mejor forma de poner el código en este sitio para que quede enmarcado al mostrarse.

Comment: Por otra parte, hazle caso a @Cris223511.dev y revisa bien desde donde estas intentando enviar ese valor, pues si no lo recibes solo puede ser porque no está enviado o bien porque intentas abrir el script directamente en tu navegador (y tal como lo tienes, siempre espera recibir el dato para funcionar bien).